# Decal on complex surfaces

Tags: uv, shrinkwrap

I need to add decals to a motorcycle. I tried to use images on planes and the shrinkwrap modifier and also to UV unwrap the surfaces, but neither method is working. The Shrinkwrap method results are distorted and it has no smooth surface.

[image: Shrinkwrap method]

The UV Unwrapping looks good, but I can't position the decal right as I place a 2d image on a 2d unwrapped mesh so it does not fit together. The real decal (cant share it) has the exact form of the side and needs to be positioned exactly.
[image]

There are two decals that fill together the red area. The decal follows the edge exactly. The suzanne suggestion has the same problem as my approach as the projected area is not 100% correct.  [image: red area is decal]

When I try to UV map the decal it's looking like that. The decal is just not fitting in the uv mesh. Do I need to pull vertices to the right place manually? Would make parts of the decal blurry I guess.
[image]

Comment: Hi :). What exactly is the problem with the UV map approach? Can you show a sketch of how it should fit together?

Answer (score 3):

so assuming you want to push a decal on suzannes ear...

[image]

drag'n drop a picture of your decal into the shader editor

and connect to your base color.

[image]

press ctrl-t when your image node is selected and you got:

[image]

requisition: i assume you have enabled the node wrangler add-on

change settings in image from repeat to clip

then go to uv editing tab

[image]

now just select the vertices where you want to add your decal to

[image]

now choose uv -> project from view (it adds the decal right in the place from your current view)

now you can select your part/vertices on the left side

[image]

and scale, rotate and move them as you need it and as you know how to do that in the viewport.

then invert your selection (select -> invert) on the right side

and on the left side select all and press s 0

press tab to go in object mode

and you got a car on the ear of suzanne

[image]